# RealmList changes when saved and queried

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I'm having issues with wrong objects being returned when a query is performed.

I have below list saved with realm

```
open class Stores : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Long = 0
    @SerializedName("totalCount")
    var totalCount: Long? = null
    @SerializedName("stores")
    var stores: RealmList<Store>? = null

}
```

And this is the Store Object

```
open class Store : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Long = 0
    @SerializedName("mainProduct")
    var mainProduct: Product? = null

}
```

And Product Object

```
open class Product : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Long = 0
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null
    @SerializedName("cost")
    var cost: String? = null

}
```

All **Store** objects with the same PrimaryKey have the same object returned which is the last Store with the same PrimaryKey saved, when below query is made:

```
  override fun getStores(realm: Realm): Stores? {
        return realm.where(Stores::class.java).equalTo("id", 0L).findFirst()
  }
```

Any help on how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. 'All Store objects with the same PrimaryKey have the same object returned which is the last Store with the same PrimaryKey saved'. A primary key is used as a unique index for the object; you cannot create multiple objects with the same primary key, you will actually just be updating the one object each time. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you are overwriting the previous object, then you shouldn't expect to query the previous object.